# Nested item properties inaccessible when using Ng-Repeat

Tags: angularjs

Are there known issues with using ng-repeat with nested objects? I have the following JSON data:

```
{
Table: [
{
contract_type: "Division Level"
}
],
Table1: [
{
division: "Illinois"
}
],
Table2: [
{
cost_center: "8646 - Administration"
}
],
Table3: [
{
organization: "XYZ"
},
{
organization: "ABC"
}
],
Table4: [
{
settingname: "Medical Care",
HCO: "XYZ"
},
{
settingname: "Progressive Care",
HCO: "ABC"
}
]
}
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<li class="twocolumns">
    <label>Contract Type:</label>
    <label>{{displayFields.Table[0].contract_type}}</label>
</li>
<li class="twocolumns">
    <label>Division:</label>
    <label>{{displayFields.Table1[0].division}}</label>
</li>
<li class="twocolumns">
    <label>Cost Center:</label>
    <label>{{displayFields.Table2[0].cost_center}}</label>
</li>

<li ng-repeat="item in displayFields.Table4[0]" class="twocolumns">
    <label>{{item.settingname}}</label>
    <label>{{item.HCO}}</label>
    foo
</li>
```

Resulting in this output:

Contract Type:Division Level 
Division: Illinois 
Cost Center:8646 - Administration 
foo 
foo

As you can see by the two lines of "foo", ng-repeat is seeing the items and iterating through them. However, accessing item properties like item.settingname is not working.

We are using angular 1.2.0-rc2, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over this:

```
item in displayFields.Table4[0]
```

When in fact, you want to iterate over `Table4` itself. Removing the `[0]` should work, since the `repeat` will base itself on the array associated to `Table4`. As it is, you're trying to iterate on the first object of `Table4`'s array.

The two `foo` outputs refer to `settingname` and `HCO` themselves and not an actual element of `Table4`. What's trully happening here is that angular is trying to print this:

The first iteration of the `ng-repeat` takes `item` as `Table4[0].settingname`, resulting in this:

```
<label>{{Table4[0].settingname.settingname}}</label>
<label>{{Table4[0].settingname.HCO}}</label>
```

Both of these attributes are undefiend, resulting in nothing. The `foo` at the end is, then, printed.

The second iteration is exactly the same, with the exception of `item` being `Table4[0].HCO`.

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate through the objects attributes

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in yourCollection">
    <label>{{key}}</label>
    <label>{{value}}</label>
</li>
```

greetings